# How to get index of an item contained in a dataSnapshot

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a query that returns a list of elements sorted according to a specific criterion (return to a DataSnapShot) and I would like to know the position occupied by a particular item in this list (whose ID, I know) without going through sequentially all the items of my list as in the code snippet below:

```
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren ()) {....}
```

Because this instruction will take a long time if my list becomes long.

Is there a faster way to access this item?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in operation to get the index of a child node in a snapshot, so you will have to do that yourself. If you just need one item, you could simply keep a counter in the loop. But if you want to perform regular lookups, you might want to store the child nodes in a way that allows faster lookups.

The [`FirebaseArray` class](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseArray.java) from the `FirebaseUI` library for example keeps a `List` of the child snapshots to allow efficient index-based lookups.

Many developers keep two lists: one with the keys, and one with the `child.getValue(...)` objects. But I personally find keeping those two in sync a bigger burden, than the performance benefits it delivers. YMMV though.